# Gatling distribution

Tags: performance, load, automated-tests, load-testing, gatling

We are considering to use Gatling as a load-testing tool.
Our scenario is very simple (invoke urls from a file), but we need to reach more than ~200K requests-per-second.
This seems to require distribution. 

Any nice distribution options available?

Answer (score 5):

To fire such a load from one client is most probably not a good approach. What you can do is to [distribute the load](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/cookbook/scaling_out.html) and fire the ~200K from more clients. Then you need to just collect `simulation.log` files or enable [real time monitoring](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/realtime_monitoring/index.html). Your only remaining problem is to start the clients almost at the same time. This will not be accurate thus plan with warm-up phase (ramp-up to target rate) and pauses in your scenario.

The setup from article ["Real Time Gatling Results With Docker And Influxdb"](http://www.dblooman.com/docker/2015/02/22/real-time-gatling-results-with-docker-and-influxdb/)  worked for us.

Seeing your desired load I assume there will be no "rocket science" logic behind. I mean no sophisticated workflow with handling too much state on client, etc. In such a case you can use *bees with machine guns* as an alternative to distribute your load. You can read more [here](https://www.happycloudsolutions.com.au/blog/bees-with-machine-guns-or-how-to-load-test-your-applicationcorporate-website-for-a-cup-of-coffee-with-the-help-of-amazon-web-services/) or [here](http://blog.bluemalkin.net/load-testing-on-ec2-using-bees-with-machine-guns/)

Comment: Is it possible to distribute the load and have real time monitoring as well. The reason i am asking is i briefly looked at the script (https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/cookbook/scaling_out/) to distribute the load. It fetches the results at the end. Please correct me if am wrong or there is another way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Gatling's FrontLine (commercial product) will be released soon.

Comment: Is there a free solution of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the gatling extension we built to support cluster based execution for gatling simulations, DistGatling is developed at walmart Technology to enable developers and QA engineers to run gatling simulation tests in a distributed/cluster environment.The solution is cloud native and has two components, Cluster Master and Cluster Worker.
https://github.com/Abiy/distGatling